# Ubuntu 19.04 Nvidia card only partially recognized

Tags: nvidia, 19.04

I got a new machine and Ubuntu installed without issue.  Supporting my Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660 Ti graphics card, however, is just not quite happening.  My monitor should be getting resolution of 2560x1440, as my older computer and nvidia card get on same monitor, but is only reaching 1900x1200.  The first odd thing I see is that two X servers are running:

```
# ps auwx | grep X
root     10883  0.0  0.2 182428 47996 tty1     Sl+  14:43   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/123/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
root     11087  1.1  0.3 200736 63224 tty7     Sl+  14:44   0:21 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt7 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3
```

Maybe ok (?), but I have only one screen.  After installing nvidia support and rebooting, things mostly look ok:

```
# nvidia-smi 
Sat Sep  7 13:37:53 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.40       Driver Version: 430.40       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:09:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 28%   36C    P8    17W / 120W |    439MiB /  5935MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1409      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            18MiB |
|    0      1455      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          48MiB |
|    0      1708      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           115MiB |
|    0      1838      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         173MiB |
|    0      2999      G   ...uest-channel-token=16139733089795658592    81MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also:

```
# inxi -SGx
System:
  Host: ab3ap Kernel: 5.0.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 8.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.32.2 Distro: Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ZOTAC driver: nvidia v: 430.40 bus ID: 09:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: nvidia 
  resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.40 
  direct render: Yes 
# dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-430:amd64                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-430                          430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-418:amd64                   430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        Transitional package for libnvidia-compute-430
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64                   430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-430:i386                    430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:amd64                    430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-430:i386                     430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:amd64                    430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-430:i386                     430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:amd64                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386                       430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:amd64                        430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-430:i386                         430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:amd64                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386                       430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-430                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-430                               430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-418                             430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-driver-430
ii  nvidia-driver-430                             430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-430                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-430                      430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.10                               all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               418.56-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-430                              430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430                 430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

And the kernel module is there:

```
# find /usr/lib/modules -name nvidia.ko -exec modinfo {} \;
filename:       /usr/lib/modules/5.0.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
alias:          char-major-195-*
version:        430.40
supported:      external
license:        NVIDIA [...]
```

However, the bad news coupled with lower res:

```
# nvidia-detector 
none
```

I'm stumped at the moment.  Any ideas gratefully appreciated!

Mike

Comment: Problem solved.  Reading up on my old monitor, HDMI max resolution is 1900x1200.  My old Nvidia card had a DVI connector, but this one has HDMI and Display Port.  Simply swapping out hdmi for DP fixed it.  A bit embarrassing.  :-P

Comment: Hello, @Mike, instead of changing the title to SOLVED, it is better to write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: You are welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. Reading up on my old monitor, HDMI max resolution is 1900x1200. My old Nvidia card had a DVI connector, but this one has HDMI and Display Port. Simply swapping out hdmi for DP fixed it. A bit embarrassing. :-P

Comment: No need for embarrassment, this will help people in the future.